# sendmail send Authentication-Warning

Tags: postfix, centos7, sendmail

Dears,
I receive successful message from postfix/pip in Centos7 (delivered via spamassassin service) while it doesn't deliver email to user with sendmail Authentication warning log. you can find log in the bellow.

```
mail postfix/pipe[33055]: 586D85F1EE: to=<root@servername.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=103, delays=0.06/0.02/0/103, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
mail postfix/qmgr[1778]: 586D85F1EE: removed
mail postfix/smtpd[46730]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpb046763: Authentication-Warning: servername.com: spamfilter set sender to MAILER-DAEMON using -f
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpb046763: from=MAILER-DAEMON, size=15920, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201807010715.w617Fcg4089763@servername.com>, relay=spamfilter@localhost
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpb046763: SYSERR(spamfilter): Too many hops 27 (25 max): from MAILER-DAEMON via localhost, to root@servername.com
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpb046763: w617bxpc046763: DSN: Too many hops 27 (25 max): from MAILER-DAEMON via localhost, to root@servername.com
mail postfix/smtpd[53780]: connect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
mail postfix/smtpd[53780]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
mail sendmail[46763]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
mail postfix/smtpd[53780]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <MAILER-DAEMON@servername.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<> to=<MAILER-DAEMON@servername.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<servername.com>
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpc046763: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=46944, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpc046763: w617bxpd046763: return to sender: User unknown
mail postfix/smtpd[53780]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <postmaster@servername.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<> to=<postmaster@servername.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<servername.com>
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpd046763: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=47968, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpc046763: Losing ./qfw617bxpc046763: save    mail panic
mail sendmail[46763]: w617bxpc046763: SYSERR(spamfilter): savemail: cannot save rejected e    mail anywhere
mail postfix/smtpd[53780]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
mail postfix/pipe[33055]: 8C1105F1EF: to=<root@servername.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=104, delays=0.3/0.03/0/103, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (service unavailable)
mail postfix/qmgr[1778]: 8C1105F1EF: removed
```

What is the Authentication-Warning? and why it said `Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table`?

**Update**
I add users to sendmail.mc file but it doesn't fix the issue. there is also `SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism` in log? what does it mean and where can I fix authentication mechanism.

```
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: connect from unknown[178.141.251.45]
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: warning: unknown[178.141.251.45]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: disconnect from unknown[178.141.251.45]
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73D004593: Authentication-Warning: servername.com: spamfilter set sender to MAILER-DAEMON using -f
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73D004593: from=MAILER-DAEMON, size=15920, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201807030512.w635CkWe044938@servername.com>, relay=spamfilter@localhost
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73D004593: SYSERR(spamfilter): Too many hops 27 (25 max): from MAILER-DAEMON via localhost, to root@servername.com
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73D004593: w635Z73E004593: DSN: Too many hops 27 (25 max): from MAILER-DAEMON via localhost, to root@servername.com
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: connect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
mail sendmail[4593]: STARTTLS=client, relay=[127.0.0.1], version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits=256/256
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <MAILER-DAEMON@servername.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<> to=<MAILER-DAEMON@winwinmarke$    mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73E004593: to=MAILER-DAEMON, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=46944, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73E004593: w635Z73F004593: return to sender: User unknown
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 <postmaster@servername.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual mailbox table; from=<> to=<postmaster@servername.com> $    mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73F004593: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=47968, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73E004593: Losing ./qfw635Z73E004593: save    mail panic
mail sendmail[4593]: w635Z73E004593: SYSERR(spamfilter): savemail: cannot save rejected e    mail anywhere
mail postfix/smtpd[4579]: disconnect from unknown[127.0.0.1]
mail postfix/pipe[4591]: BBCB623331: to=<root@servername.com>, relay=spamassassin, delay=104, delays=0.05/0.02/0/103, dsn=5.3.0, status=bounced (service unavailable)
mail postfix/qmgr[69009]: BBCB623331: removed
mail postfix/smtpd[18405]: connect from unknown[161.132.201.90]
mail postfix/smtpd[18405]: warning: unknown[161.132.201.90]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
mail postfix/smtpd[18405]: disconnect from unknown[161.132.201.90]
mail postfix/smtpd[29270]: connect from unknown[94.16.117.217]
mail postfix/smtpd[29270]: warning: unknown[94.16.117.217]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
mail postfix/smtpd[29270]: disconnect from unknown[94.16.117.217]
mail postfix/anvil[39360]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:178.141.251.45) at Jul  3 05:33:37
mail postfix/anvil[39360]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:178.141.251.45) at Jul  3 05:33:37
mail postfix/anvil[39360]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Jul  3 05:33:37
mail postfix/smtpd[43131]: connect from unknown[46.244.212.248]
mail postfix/smtpd[43131]: warning: unknown[46.244.212.248]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: Invalid authentication mechanism
mail postfix/smtpd[43131]: disconnect from unknown[46.244.212.248]
```

Comment: Are you really running Postfix and Sendmail at the same time on the same machine? That's not a good idea at all!

Answer (score 1):

The Authentication-Warning message logs the fact that a mail message was submitted by user `spamfilter` but the user set (you could also say: forged) the sender address `MAILER-DAEMON`. It is really just a warning and does not prevent delivery of the message.

The message `User unknown in virtual mailbox table` tells you that your Postfix installation does not know the mail addresses `MAILER-DAEMON@servername.com` (in the first instance) and `postmaster@servername.com` (in the second one). The reason may be simply that you forgot to add the usual definitions for these in your aliases file.

Answer (score 1):

> Authentication-Warning: servername.com: spamfilter set sender to MAILER-DAEMON using -f

In addition to what [Tilman Schmidt explained](https://serverfault.com/a/919044/37681) you resolve that by adding the system user from the error message, `spamfilter` in this case, to the list of sendmail trusted users.

In your sendmail.mc 
either define trusted users directly with:

```
define(`confTRUSTED_USERS',`root daemon spamfilter')
```

or set:

```
FEATURE(`use_ct_file')
define(`confCT_FILE', `/etc/mail/trusted-users')
```

And add the trusted users such as `spamfilter` to either the default `/etc/mail/trusted-users` configuration file a custom location.

Comment: it doesn't fix the issue. `from=<>` is empty. Is it OK?

Comment: I update a question with new log